# SharedPreferences confuse the values

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

In my code I use two methods called in certain order.

1)

```
public void setWhoseSelected(int newWhoseSelected) {
    this.whoseSelected = newWhoseSelected;
    sharedEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    sharedEditor.putInt(getString(R.string.whoseHome), newWhoseSelected);
    sharedEditor.apply();
}
```

2)

```
  public void setSortSelected(int newSortSelected) {
        this.sortSelected = newSortSelected;
        sharedEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        sharedEditor.putInt(getString(R.string.sortHome), newSortSelected);
        sharedEditor.apply();
    }
```

But what I noticed is that it sets both "R.string.whoseHome" and "R.string.sortHome" to the same newSortSelected value. While trying to understand the problem I tried to switch their places and then both of them saved newWhoseSelected to SP. So as I understand, the last setter called sets its value to both of strings. Due to some restrictions I can't set them in one method and then apply().

I also tried to create separate Editor for each, but it didn't help. So how does this work and how can I edit values twice w/o confusing them?

I'm a bit embarrassed, so thank you in advance!

Comment: Tell me if i am wrong , you want two separate values for two diff strings ?

Comment: @SantanuSur right. Like I set 1 to whoseHome, and 2 to sortHome, but after that I get 2 in both of strings. That's the problem, and I can't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in your `strings.xml` you have set the *same* value for both string resource like

```
 <string name="sortHome">xyz</string>
 <string name="whoseHome">xyz</string>
```

So change it and give **`UNIQUE`** value to **`UNIQUE`** string resource.

Comment: Wow, it really works, but still strange. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: why strange ? @asmodeoux

Comment: i didn't know i can't set the same default value for 2 different strings, it was really confusing